# Solving equations involving exponential and line

Tags: functions, exponential-function

[image]

I understand how to do (a): y=(p-1)x/(lnp) +-p-1
but I have no idea where to start in (b) and how to solve it. Where did the k come from?

Comment: can we clarify the source of the question? is it an ongoing exam? also please include the solution for part a so that the rest don't repeat the same effort.

Comment: $k$ appears to be an arbitrary nonzero real number. The question asks you to solve for $x$ in terms of $k$.

Comment: For part (b), the equation is equivalent to $qx = -e^{-x} + 1$ where $q = (e^k - 1)/k > 0$. Looking at the graph, there are at most 2 solutions for $x$. I'm still not sure how to find them, though.

Comment: Elaborating on my previous comment, there are exactly 2 solutions for $x$. One of them is $0$. The other one is positive when $q < 1$ and negative when $q > 1$. Due to the horizontal asymptote of the RHS, for $q \ll 1$, the nonzero solution is approximately $1/q$. I'm not sure much else can be said.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer for part (a) is $$y(x) = \frac{p-1}{\ln(p)}x + p - 1.$$

This is easily found by finding the $x$ and $y$ intercepts and using the equation for a line between two points.

For part (b), we can rearrange the equation to obtain $$\frac{e^k - 1}{k}x = -e^{-x} + 1.$$ Let $g(x)$ be the LHS and $h(x)$ be the RHS. Note that the slope of $g$ is equal to the slope of $y$ with $p = e^k$, and $h$ is just $f$ with $p = 1$. Also note that $h(0) = 0$.

*Side note: This observation makes it clear why part (a) had the condition $p > 1$. If $p = 1$, the $x$ and $y$ intercepts are the same point, so there is no unique line that intersects both.*

Let $p = e^k$ and observe that $g(x) = y(x) - p + 1$ and $h(x) = f(x) - p + 1$. Remember that we are trying to solve $g(x) = h(x)$. Using this result, we transform that problem into solving $y(x) = f(x)$.

By the definition of $y$, If $y(x) = f(x)$, then $x = 0$ (the $y$ intercept) or $y(x) = 0$ (the $x$ intercept). Solving $y(x) = 0$, we obtain $x = -k$. Therefore, the solutions are $x = 0$ and $x = -k$.

*Side note: Regrettably, this answer does not really show the process by which I discovered the approach, which primarily involved graphing things to visualize the problem and looking for patterns. Either way, I hope it helps.*

Comment: +1 Amazing! However, I believe this question went against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) and shouldn't have been answered before being improved.

Comment: @AnneBauval Oops. I didn't realize it was against policy to answer low quality questions. Thanks for letting me know.